# Get the cumulative bytes sent and received from a NIC

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, prtg

Is there an easy way (via a script perhaps) to get the cumulative bytes sent and received from a [NIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) on [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008)?

For example, the NIC currently shows around 18 MB of sent data and 765 MB of received data.

Since my server provider does not provide an easy way to see the monthly bandwidth usage, getting the NIC data seems to be the most reliable one.

I know I can use [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) to get the current usage data via [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol), but it will only be an average since the sensor checks every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PowerShell (CTP2v3), the commands below will help. (I have three interfaces). However, once the NIC was restarted, this information will zero out.

```
$computer = "LocalHost";
$namespace = "root\CIMV2";
$Tcpip_NI = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -computername $computer -namespace $namespace;
$Tcpip_NI | Select BytesReceivedPersec, BytesSentPersec, BytesTotalPersec;

$netsh_interface_stats = netsh interface ip show interface;
$netsh_interface_stats | Select-string "In Octets";
$netsh_interface_stats | Select-string "Out Octets";
```

Comment: also (without PowerShell) `wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface get BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec,BytesTotalPersec`

Answer (score 2):

Does `netstat -e` help? It doesn't seem to distinguish between NICs, though you may get your maintenance interface traffic mixed into that as well.

Otherwise this sounds like something for [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) and [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [IronRuby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronRuby) or [IronPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) script and use the [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.aspx) namespace although it would probably be easier to whip up a quick C# or VB.NET console application.

You probably need the class [IPv4InterfaceStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics_properties.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just a brief note:

The following works perfectly for me - a heads up that the number wraps negative and you will need to build in some logic for that.  I'm operating in a mixed environment and do not have PowerShell available on everything, so my solution is to use [WMIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation):

```
wmic Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface Get BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec,BytesTotalPersec
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an existing solution for my own problem, [PRTG Network Monitor](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) version 7.

It has sensors to interface with [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) and get the network card data. Very nice :)